# Is an ISIC (International Student Identity Card) valid proof of student status for reduced fee Vatican City tickets?

Tags: tickets, budget, price, museums, vatican-city

I want to visit Vatican city and want to get a reduced entrance ticket. Is getting an [ISIC card](https://www.isic.org/) the only way, or maybe a university student identity document translated in English will be enough for getting a reduced ticket?

Comment: What are you calling a student identity document? If it is a certificate from your uni that says you are enrolled on a full-time course for the current academic year, then having a translation may not work in Italy. You can use that certificate, however, to get the ISIC (which is only 12,5 Euro). The small **ID card from your uni with your picture** is what is needed; that, or an [ISIC card](http://www.isicgreece.gr/en/isic-card/).

Comment: What is an ISIC card? Which country is this university based in?

Comment: @JoErNanO it's an [International Student Identity Card](https://www.isic.org/) which has been around for more than 60 years and is available in more than 130 countries. I believe OP identified her country as Greece,

Comment: @user568458 The question was unclear. It has now been edited, by OP, me and others, and is much clearer. This is how SE works. Isn't it?

Comment: @Dorothy Awesome link I added it to the post.

Answer (score 4):

For the Vatican Museums and the Sistine Chapel, which are on a combined ticket, I think you'll find what you want here: http://mv.vatican.va/3_EN/pages/z-Info/MV_Info_Biglietto.html

> Students **up to 25 years of age, on presentation of a valid International Student Card, a student identity document or other documentation** stating their registration to a university or institution of higher education, are granted the reduced price ticket

This reduces the price to €8.00 from €16.00 - price and entry info here: http://mv.vatican.va/3_EN/pages/z-Info/MV_Info_Orari.html

While it sounds like they'd accept any official documentation, given the long waits often involved in Vatican City ticketing, it's worth considering having the easily recognisable ISIC to speed the process up. But obviously don't buy the ISIC unless you're planning to visit many museums and other such places with student discounts since it costs more than the saving here. If you have a university photo ID card that's obviously a student card, most (not all) places will usually accept it without requiring ISIC.

Comment: Hahaha well spotted and I should probably also mention that the card costs more than the discount...